# Find out number of sub-list levels and flatten all into one-level list

Tags: python, list, flatten, sublist

If I have some list which has sublists, and that sublists also have sublists etc, how to flatten everything at one level? Let's assume that max sublist level is <= 10. I know how to do that for 2-3 levels by loops, but there must be some algorithm to achieve this without <= 10 for loops. All elements are different, but it does not matter.

```
L=[[a,b],[[c,d,[e,f]],[g,[[h],i],j,[k,l,m]]...] # start list
newL = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m] # resulted list
```

Comment: This answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @RadeTomovic Do you want the deepest sub-list level?

Comment: @AnandSKumar and I missed that the title of the question mentioned a count but it was never in the body of the question, so it was a duplicate after all.